# retrieving database value for a manual drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a manual drop down list that I added 3 items to (no data connection, no binding).

```
 **Text**                   **Value**
 blank space            blank space
 Dog                    6
 Cat                    7
```

I store the drop down list value as so

```
  mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ANIMAL", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ddlAnimals.SelectedItem.Text;
```

I retrieve the drop down list value as so

```
 ddlAnimals.SelectedItem.Value = mySqlDataReader[1].ToString();
```

The problem I am having is that although my drop down list populates with the correct Text (after I retrieve it), it duplicates the text in the list, and the text from the database does not have a value associated with it. If I return Dog, there is no value of 6. My drop down list, upon clicking looks like this:

```
   Dog (Currently Selected upon Click)
   Dog
   Cat
```

If I select the other Dog or the Cat Value, I retain my 6 and 7. But the original "Dog" has no value associated with the Text. What in the world am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you update your question with the full block of code that updates the dropdown list? From your small snippet, it seems as if you are *assigning* a value to the `SelectedItem`, rather than *retrieving* it.

Comment: when I retrieve it from the database, I'm just taking the value in the database and displaying it in the ddl. From just typing that, I can tell I did something very wrong.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code that handles the dropdown list selection change?

Comment: is that what I am missing? I have no method for that.....

Comment: In your question, you mention "*I retrieve the drop down list value as so*" - where's the code that does that? Show the full code block.

Comment: I think you need the `Value` instead of `Text` here,  `Parameters.AddWithValue("@ANIMAL", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ddlAnimals.SelectedItem.Value;`

Comment: Clear the Dropdown list and add items to it,so that you won't be able to see duplicate items in dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

Before you are loading your dropdown list clear the items and then reload it.Like this :

```
ddlAnimals.Items.Clear();
```

Use `ddlAnimals.SelectedValue` to pass the parameters like this :

```
mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ANIMAL", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ddlAnimals.SelectedValue;
```